# Shared values across all devices?

Tags: swift, core-data, ios8, plist, icloud

I have an app where I'd like configurations to be modified in some web backend.

My initial thought was to store the default values in a plist file, then request updated values from a remote server via JSON. I don't like this because it's asynchronous, so updates in the web admin will not be instant, just if the user kills the app and reopens it (some configurations are needed very early such as changing the global tint.

Another idea I had is if all mobile devices use a shared file in iCloud. Is it possible for all users who've downloaded my app to access the same file synchronously in the cloud? Or does Core Data have a shared area for all devices to read for example?

Any ideas or experiences on how to handle what I'm trying to accomplish? Thanks for any advice or insight.

Answer (score 0):

If you have data that you want to share with all users of your app, you could use public database in [CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html). It is asynchronous, but you can subscribe your users to receive changes once they are available.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is what you said. A configuration file on a server that you download.

You can simply download the file when the app is launched, but only apply the changes the next time the app is launched.

Your other options are a wait screen while you load the resource, or allowing the app to reconfigure when it gets the updated file.

The loading screen is essential if your configuration file contains changes you want applied right away e.g. privacy policy url, or something like that.

Reconfiguration on download is complicated and if you are changing things like themes, it will provide a bad user experience.

There is one final option. You can use push notifications (silent notifications) when there is a new version of your file. You can then download it in the background.